# How to enable USB debugging on Sony Xperia Z1

Tags: debugging, usb, sony-xperia

I am unable to find USB debugging on the new Xperia Z1 handset. Various sources suggest that it is under **"Settings > Applications > Developer > USB Debugging".** However, there is no "Applications", "Developer" or anything remotely of use within the settings app.

```
    Device Info is as follows:
    Model No. C6903
    Android 4.2.2
    Kernel 3.4.0-perf-gde8296d-02197-ga764ca1
    Build No. 14.1.G.1.5331
```

Is there a way to enable it, or am I missing something?

Comment: On my phone I can find the "Developer options" if I open the settings app and scroll all the way down to the bottom.

Answer (score 86):

I found the cause. It's a 4.2 development that hides the USB debugger by default.

> "Android 4.2 and higher, the Developer options screen is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options." - Found at: http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html

At least now it should appear in search results more easily!

Comment: Thought I was being trolled by SO here... Amazing :')

Comment: On my Xperia V (Android 4.3), dev stuff is under... "Settings -> Developer options" ^_^

Comment: Thank you very much. It works for me. Indeed after tapping seven times, developer options is added to the root pane of setting.

Answer (score 20):

Thanks @Dezzamondo for your answer. In addition to tapping the Build number 7 times (in `Settings > About Phone`) you will also need to install the drivers on the host computer. Here is a link to the [Sony mobile drivers](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/), this is where the Z1 drivers can be found.